# Need To Extract String After '@' & Before ' ' (Blank Space) Multiple Times

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm working on extracting twitter/facebook style mentions from a textbox.
So far, here's my code:

```
  Dim a As String = TextBox1.Text + " "
        Dim b As Char() = a.ToCharArray
        Dim c As String
        Dim l As Integer = TextBox1.Text.Length
        Dim temp As Integer = 0
        Dim nex As Integer = a.IndexOf(" ")
        For i = 0 To l - 1

            If b(i) = "@" Then
                temp = 1
            ElseIf temp = 1 Then
              temp = 2
            End If

            If temp = 2 Then

                c = a.Substring(i, nex).Trim() 'nex needs be replaced with next space on 2nd or nth loop
                MsgBox(c)
                temp = 0
                nex = a.IndexOf(" ") + nex
            End If

        Next
```

> Now this works great if the entered text is- @one @twwo @three. (If
>   the next strings are greater in length.) But doesn't work elsewhere.

Also, there is probably going to be content between two @mentions so I'm not willing to change the b(i).

I'm sure there's a much more efficient way to do this.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `regex`.  The pattern `@\w+` should do nicely.

```
For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches("@testing this is a @test", "@\w+")
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value)
Next
```

Will print out `@testing` and `@test`.

This pattern basically means "Find everything that starts with an '@' followed by one or more 'word characters'."

Regex is a very powerful tool for searching strings, you can read more about it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I don't know exactly what characters are allowed in twitter user names, so it's possible this may miss a few, or even match a few things that it shouldn't, but it should be pretty accurate.  If you see it finding things it shouldn't, or missing something, just let me know what those are and I will adjust the pattern for you.  For example, this will only return "@first" when looking at "@first.last".

Comment: Surely. I'll check for cases and drop a comment if something fails to abide by my wishes. :) Thanks again. This made work a lot easier. :D